# I need truly blank cells from Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a formula

```
=I2&""=DATE(YEAR(I2)+3,MONTH(I2),DAY(I2))
```

that returns a date plus 3 years from the referenced cell.

It returns FALSE when the referenced cell is blank.

I would really like it to return a truly empty cell when the referenced cell is blank.

Previously I ran this formula without the modification `=I2""` and it would return the earliest date that Excel 2010 recognizes plus three years and I used conditional formatting to change the font to white so that it didn't show up when printing.

What can I change with this formula to return a truly blank cell?

Answer (score 1):

Excel does not have a function to return a truly empty cell.

A suggestion to add this functionality has been presented to Microsoft at the [Excel.Uservoice.com](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/9095062-give-us-a-proper-null-worksheet-function) site. You can add your vote. The more votes a feature request gets, the higher the likelihood that it will be implemented.